# send (all) from command line

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

In the desktop wallet you can send your entire balance but clicking the "All" button which puts (all) in the amount.  Is there a way to do the same thing in the command line client?

Comment: Kind of duplicate of that ^ question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sweep_all` command. It will send the full balance, minus the fee needed for that transaction. For example:

sweep_all 4aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

See `help` in monero-wallet-cli for full command syntax.